# Calling other functions only after getting result from ajax call in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my function:

```
loadChildNodes($('#budgetline' + id));
$('.child-of-budgetline' + id).each(function(){
    $(this).expandTreeNode();
    console.log("test");
});
```

loadChildNodes($element) function makes an ajax call. I want to wait until this function is completed and then only execute the lines after it. But doesnot happen so. How can i make the other lines execute only after the function loadChildNodes has completed.

Comment: could you post `loadChildNodes` function too? What does it return?

Comment: You might have to use a callback for this, does `loadChildNodes($element)` returns anything? can you post the code of this method?

Answer (score 2):

use a promise available by [`deferred objects`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
$.when(loadChildNodes($('#budgetline' + id))).done(function() {
    $('.child-of-budgetline' + id).each(function(){
       $(this).expandTreeNode();
       console.log("test");
    });
})
.fail(function() {
   /* some errors occured */
})
```

To properly work `loadChildNodes()` should return either a `promise` (to resolve on ajax success callback and reject on error callback) or the ajax object itself (`$.ajax` or other shortcut, like `$.get`, `$.post`...)

Answer (score 1):

Use [$.when().then()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)  to do stuff once AJAX completes, e.g:

```
$.when(loadChildNodes($('#budgetline' + id))).then(function() { 
    //stuff 
});
```

Comment: Then i think you will need to return the ajaxObject from `loadChildNodes` - right?

Comment: That's right, and you can then execute any success handlers attached to the `ajaxObject`. But be warned that `success()` is being deprecated in favour of `done()` see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a `callback` parameter for `loadChildNodes` and call that callback in the success callback of ajax call inside that method.
Now refactor your code in way that the remaining lines of code will be moved to callback and passed to loadChildNodes method.

```
loadChildNodes($('#budgetline' + id), function() {
   $('.child-of-budgetline' + id).each(function(){     
     $(this).expandTreeNode();     
     console.log("test"); 
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to return the ajax call as an object :

```
loadChildNodes($('#budgetline' + id)).done(function() {
    $('.child-of-budgetline' + id).each(function(){
        $(this).expandTreeNode();
        console.log("test");
    });
});

function loadChildNodes(elem) {
    return $.ajax({

       //do ajax
    });
}
```